# PHP ignoring <?= $var ?> blocks

Tags: php

**Note:** I'm using PHP 5.3.3 on a CentOS 6 server.

I'm testing out a new web host and I've discovered that it is simply ignoring the `<?= $var ?>` blocks of PHP code. For instance, if I have this in a PHP file:

```
<div id='<?=$page_id?>'>
```

Then it does not display the value of `$page_id`, it writes it just as you see there. On the other hand, if I write:

```
<div id='<?php echo $page_id; ?>'>
```

Then it displays the variable as it should. On its own, this isn't a big deal. Unfortunately I have a TONNE of inherited code that uses the `<?= $var ?>` syntax all over the place, so I'd like to avoid having to change it all.

Does anyone know what setting I have to change in order for PHP to recognize this syntax? Our old server was running PHP 5.3.14 and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. Thank you. It proved very difficult to search for this problem and get sensible results.

Comment: Without knowing to search for "PHP short tags" or "short open tag", yes, it would be.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [enable short tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).